# Partially transparent Android Actionbar in my xml

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-actionbar

In my project I need to set the actionbar partially transparent in every my activity.

I use this code that works well:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.argb(128, 27, 56, 100)));
```

But I would to set this 'configuration' in my custom actionbar xml style to avoid duplicating this code for each activity. Is possible this?

The current actionBar xml style is this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="background">@color/ActionBarColor</item>
        <item name="logo">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of your color (ActionBarColor) to have a transparency.  The first 2 characters of the 8 char code are used for transparency (00 = Full transparency, FF = No transparency).

So, your color value would be #00ffffff (to have a fully transparent black color).

Once you have set this color with the proper transparency, you can set it the same as you set any other color.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<item name="android:color">#801B3864</item>
```

to your xml

Comment: In this way I see my ActionBar 100% transparent... I would to replicate exactly this: Color.argb(128, 27, 56, 100)